# Fixing a Runtime error in VBA Access on Exported Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out an issue I'm having with my code.

I'm trying to export a file to excel and the using conditional formatting delete the unique. 
The first time I run this it works perfectly.

If I run it a second time while a file is already in the folder I end up with a *"runtime error  Method 'Rows' of object_gobal' failed"* on the line `lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row` Trying to skip this line just gives me the same type of error on the next line.

I'd like to be able to run this and have it just overwrite or create a second version of the file without the error and continue with the conditional formatting I am asking it to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
'Build Retail Bump File Pass Through Query
db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryRetailBumpFile"
Set qdfPassThrough = db.CreateQueryDef("qryRetailBumpFile")
qdfPassThrough.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SupplyChainMisc;Description=SupplyChainMisc;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=SupplyChain_Misc;"
qdfPassThrough.ReturnsRecords = True
qdfPassThrough.Sql = StrSQL

'Create Excel File
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim lrow As Long

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryRetailBumpFile", "\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Company Bumps(WORK IN PROGRESS)\RETAILS\Test\" & strBrand & "\" & strSeason & "\" & strPrefix & "\" & strPrefix & " " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail.xlsx", True

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Company Bumps(WORK IN PROGRESS)\RETAILS\Test\" & strBrand & "\" & strSeason & "\" & strPrefix & "\" & strPrefix & " " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail.xlsx")
appExcel.Visible = True


With myWorkbook.worksheets("qryRetailBumpFile")
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row <-- Error here

.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlUnique

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
.Range("A1").Select

'Filter Color and delete
.Range("A1:M" & lrow).AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:M" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(5, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("qryRetailBumpFile")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row
    If lr < 2 Then Exit Sub
    .Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lr - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
.Range("A1:M" & lrow).AutoFilter
End With
myWorkbook.Close

Set appExcel = Nothing
Set myWorkbook = Nothing
db.Close
```

Thanks!
-Deke

Comment: You're not actually referencing that `myWorkbook` at all btw.... it should be a `Worksheet` object, e.g. `With myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`, and then you need periods before all your `Range` and `Cells` and `Rows` calls.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the quick reply. Can you elaborate? I have `Dim myWorkbook as Excel.Workbook` and I have it `Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Company Bumps(WORK IN PROGRESS)\RETAILS\Test\" & strBrand & "\" & strSeason & "\" & strPrefix & "\" & strPrefix & " " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail.xlsx")` and I missing something else?

Comment: I meant the `With myWorkbook`, sorry.. also `Set appExcel = Nothing` and `Set myWorkbook = Nothing` don't belong in that spot at all.

Comment: I had actually tried something like `With myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryRetailBumpFile")` and then the periods for all my range and cell calls but what I ended up with was another debug error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the `.lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row` line. Also I moved the `set appExcel` and `set myWorkbook...` at the end just before `db.close` statement.

Comment: `lrow  = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @BigBen I've updated my code I'm now getting an off the wall error saying " The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" Getting this on the `lrow = .cells` line.

Comment: I think you also want `myWorkbook.Close` at the end of this routine... you don't want to open an already workbook, right.

Comment: You declare lrow variable but use lr in two places and lr is not declared. Is this supposed to be another variable? Should use Option Explicit in module header.

Comment: @BigBen you are correct. I've added the the close statement at the end. But still getting the original runtime error on the lrow line. I'll keep playing with, thanks for your input!!

Comment: @June7 thanks for the advice! This is part of a much larger routine. I gave the section I know the issue is focused in. It's not something that is running from a module but rather a form I created.

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question with the latest version of your code.

Comment: @BigBen updated

Comment: `lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`... periods make a difference.